# Javascript - Is it possible to base64 a remote image?

Tags: javascript, base64

I have the following

HTML

```
<img id="preview1" crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0e39d18b89822d1d9871e0d1bc839d06?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG">
```

JS

```
var img = document.getElementById("preview1");
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.width;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var result = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
console.log(result)
```

For some reason, when I paste the `result` (base64) in an `img` `src` it shows nothing. Also when I paste the `result` (base64) as a url, it shows nothing.

When I use use `input="file"` and use `FileReader()` to get the file. it works fine.

**Is it a better way to grab a remote file and convert to a working base64?**

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** The code bellow will **NOT** work with a remote image. Sorry, was running the Chrome with the '--disable-web-security' flag.

I have made a simple [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhpgomes/ztsag6g7/) with a working version of what you want.

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
    // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
    // will re-encode the image.
    return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}

var im = new Image();
im.onload = function(ev) {
    var im = ev.target;
    var img = document.getElementById("preview1");
    img.src = getBase64Image(im);
}
im.src = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0e39d18b89822d1d9871e0d1bc839d06?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"
```

Oh, and I shamelessly copied the getBase64Image method from this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/934925/796640)

Comment: This won't work because of the different domain. (This is exactly why this question was asked: "Is it possible to base64 a *remote* image?")

Comment: getting the cors error in the fiddle. Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Comment: Oh I see... I was developing a webapp of my own and was running Chrome with the '--disable-web-security' flag. Useful during development. Indeed this will not work with a CORS request in an usual environment.